# I have two files, how should i compare these files using shell and awk script

Tags: shell, shell-exec

I have two files

Content of file A

```
paybackFile_537214-760887_000_20120801.xml
paybackFile_354472-544899_000_20120801.xml
paybackFile_62-11033_000_20120801.xml
paybackFile_831669-837544_000_20120801.xml
===========================================
Total file(s) - 4
===========================================
```

Content of file B

```
14/08/2012 12:36:01: MSG: File paybackFile_537214-760887_000_20120801.xml.gpg decrypted successfully.
13/08/2012 11:36:01: MSG: File paybackFile_62-11033_000_20120801.xml.gpg not decrypted successfully.
```

Here i have names of *.xml files.
From file A we check that ***.xml file is present in file B and also check whether it has been decrypted successfully.

Could you please help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Smita

Comment: Here in fileA i have 100 records and in fileB i have 80 records.
From fileA i have to take the name of file which is ***.xml(from a string given above) then have to verify whether that ***.xml file(which is also a part of string) is present in fileB.
We also need to verify whether in fileB if ***.xml is present,then its decrypted successfully or not.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$2".gpg"];next}(($5 in a) && ($0~/decrypted/))' filea fileb
```

Comment: When using command

awk 'FNR==NR{a[$2".gpg"];next}(($5 in a) && ($0~/decrypted/))' filea fileb > fileC

there is no data in fileC.

fileC should have paybackFile_521000-845442_000_20120701.xml missing

Comment: The scenario is..
if file successfully found and decrypted then echo success
else print the missing or not decrypted in fileC

Answer (score 0):

Create a script named compare.awk. Paste this inside:

```
FILENAME=="fileB" && $5 ~ /xml/ {
     if ($6 == "decrypted" && $7 == "successfully.") {
         decrypted_file[$5] = 1;
     } else {
         decrypted_file[$5] = 2;
     }
}
FILENAME=="fileA" && $2 ~ /xml/ {
    if (decrypted_file[$2".gpg"] == 1) {
        print $2" exist and decrypted";
    } else if (decrypted_file[$2".gpg"] == 2) {
        print $2" exist but not decrypted";
    } else {
        print $2" not exist in fileB";
    }
}
```

Call it by:

```
awk -F' ' -f compare.awk fileB fileA
```

[EDIT] For shell without awk script, (still need grep, sed, cut and wc tho):

```
#!/bin/bash

TESTA=`grep ".xml" fileA | cut -d' ' -f2`
TESTB=`grep ".xml" fileB | cut -d' ' -f5,6,7 | sed 's/ /-/g'`
DECRYPT_YES=""
DECRYPT_NO=""

for B in ${TESTB}
do
 DECRYPT_B=`echo ${B} | sed 's/.*gpg-decrypted-successfully\./1/'`
 if [ ${DECRYPT_B} == "1" ]
 then
   DECRYPT_YES=${DECRYPT_YES}" "`echo ${B} | sed 's/\.gpg.*//g'`
 else
   DECRYPT_NO=${DECRYPT_NO}" "`echo ${B} | sed 's/\.gpg.*//g'`
 fi
done

for FILE_A in ${TESTA}
do
 if [ `echo ${DECRYPT_YES} | grep "${FILE_A}" | wc -l` == 1 ]
 then
  echo ${FILE_A}" exist and decrypted"
 elif [ `echo ${DECRYPT_NO} | grep "${FILE_A}" | wc -l` == 1 ]
 then
  echo ${FILE_A}" exist but not decrypted"
 else
  echo ${FILE_A}" not exist"
 fi
done
```

Comment: Here in fileA i have 100 records and in fileB i have 80 records.
From fileA i have to take the name of file which is ***.xml(from a string given above) then have to verify whether that ***.xml file(which is also a part of string) is present in fileB.
We also need to verify whether in fileB if ***.xml is present,then its decrypted successfully or not.

Comment: there, updated the compare.awk script. Hopefully that's what you expected to get.

Comment: Hello Andere,

Thank you,the awk script works as expected.
But cant this be done using shell script? As awk script is the second option.

Regards,
Smita

Comment: Well there's shell script, but still need sed, grep, cut and wc.

Comment: Hello, i need to have names of ***.xml files of the scenarios which are "exist but not decrypted" and "not exist" in a separate file.
How can i add this feature to the above existing code?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a script:

```
#!/bin/sh

FILEA=fileA
FILEB=fileB

awk -F" " ' { print $2 } ' $FILEA > .tmpfileA 
awk -F" " ' { print $5 } ' $FILEB | sed 's/\.gpg//' | grep 'decrypted successfully' > .tmpfileB


diff .tmpfileA .tmpfileB

rm -f .tmpfileA
rm -f .tmpfileB
```

All you'll need to change is the variables FILEA and FILEB

When executing it with the inputs you provided it gives the following result:

```
$ testAB.ksh 
2d1
< paybackFile_521000-845442_000_20120701.xml
$
```

Comment: The above script only compares whether ***.xml file present in fileB.
It does not checks whether the ***.xml file is successfully decrypted or not.

Comment: all you need is to grep 'decrypted successfully' in the second file. I updated the answer.

Comment: It just gives the names of words at second location, it doesn't even compares the data.
Also there is little change in the requirement, please look at it.