# I have two files, how should i compare these files using shell script

Tags: shell, shell-exec

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I have two files, how should i compare these files using shell and awk script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12257976/i-have-two-files-how-should-i-compare-these-files-using-shell-and-awk-script)

I have two files

Content of file A

```
File paybackFile_783205-786752_000_20120801.xml sent successfully
File paybackFile_521000-845442_000_20120701.xml sent successfully
```

Content of file B

```
14/08/2012 12:36:01: MSG: File paybackFile_783205-786752_000_20120801.xml.gpg decrypted successfully.
```

Here in fileA i have 100 records in above format and in fileB i have 80 records in above format. From fileA i have to take the name of file which is *.xml (from a string given above) then have to verify whether that *.xml file (which is also a part of string) is present in fileB. We also need to verify whether in fileB if *.xml is present,then its decrypted successfully or not.

Regards,
Smita

Comment: Please don't ask the same question twice. Rather check back with your original question there are some answers there - as you know, because you already commented on them.

Comment: Hello,
Those response werent 100% useful
Thus waiting for appropriate answer in shell script.
Thanks in advance.
Regards,
Smita